# Show that $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Show that $\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology is Hausdorff.

For any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ it is possible to define $\mathscr{U}_x=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon>0$ and $\mathscr{U}_y=(y-\delta,y+\delta)$ so that $\mathscr{U}_x\cap\mathscr{U}_y=\emptyset$.

**Question**:

Is this proof right? If not. How should I answer the question? What tools should I use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To make the proof right, verify that the intersection is empty.  For that you will have to show how to choose $\delta$ and $\epsilon$.  For example, $\delta = \epsilon = |x-y|/2$.

Comment: "...it is possible..." This assertion is not a proof on its own, but *needs* a proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument is not complete, until you find $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ such that
$$
(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap(y-\delta,y+\delta)=\emptyset
$$
Since $x\ne y$, it is not restrictive to assume $x<y$. In order the intersection above is empty, it's sufficient that
$$
x+\varepsilon<y-\delta
$$
that is, $\varepsilon+\delta<y-x$. Take
$$
\varepsilon=\delta=\frac{y-x}{3}
$$
and you're done.

Comment: Could not I take $\epsilon=\delta=\frac{|x-y|}{2}$?

Comment: @PedroGomes Yes, that would be another choice.

Answer (score 5):

Assume $x <y$. Then $$x<\frac{x+y}{2}<y$$

Here the sets $(-\infty,\frac{x+y}{2})$ and $(\frac{x+y}{2},\infty)$ makes the separation for $x$ and $y$

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do it is to choose both $$\epsilon = \delta = \frac{x+y}{2} > 0$$

Then define,

$$U_x = (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \subseteq \mathcal R$$
$$U_y = (y - \epsilon, y + \epsilon) \subseteq \mathcal R$$

As you can see, both are open intervales; therefore, they are open sets in the standard (usual) topology in $R$. In other words,

$$U_x, U_y \in \mathcal T$$

Furthermore,

$$U_x \: \cap \: U_y = \mathcal \phi$$

Comment: By your definition, $U_x, U_y$ dont have to be disjoint. Take $x=10^6$ and $y=10^6+1$ for example

Comment: Also,  $\epsilon=\delta=\frac{x+y}{2}>0$ is false. For example take $x,y$ to be any two distinct negative numbers